# how to append/replace alt/title attribute in all image tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack

say I have an action template like this

```rb
# home/index.html.erb
<%= img_tag "logo.gif" %>
```

if I want to add alt/title attribute to it, I can just do

```rb
# home/index.html.erb
<%= img_tag "logo.gif", alt: "alt!!", title: "title!!" %>
```

but I have 1000 image tags and I don't want to change every each one of them.

I then thought of using rack middleware and modify image tags before outputting from server.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast

```rb
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(@response.body)
doc.search("img").each do |tag|
  [:alt, :title].each{|attribute| tag[attribute] = "changed!!" }
end
```

but when I follow the railscast episode, it **appends** entire body on the top of the original rather than **replacing** it.

Am I doing it wrong in the rack, or is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
# /config/initializers/image_tag_helper.rb

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetTagHelper
      def image_tag(source, options={})
        options[:src] = path_to_image(source)
        options[:alt] = "Default Alt" unless options.has_key?(:alt)
        options[:title] = "Default Title" unless options.has_key?(:title)
        tag(:img, options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This overrides the `image_tag` helper method to set default `alt` and `title` attributes.

Comment: thanks, this will work, but I was searching for a way not to change the current templates.